# Auto generate random long in IntelliJ Live Template

Tags: intellij-idea, auto-generate, live-templates

How do I auto generate an arbitrary number (Long) for use in a Live Template in IntelliJ?

Example:

```
public static final long uid = $randomLong$;
```

where `randomLong` is replaced with a random long value. I have tried adding the following as an expression for the variable on the live template definition but nothing is generated when the template outputs.

```
new Random().nextLong()
```

What I am trying to achieve is very similar to what the IDEA code inspector generates for the Serialization version UID field but with a live template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try adding `groovyScript("new Random().nextLong()")` as the variable expression instead.